# Consolidate several rows into a single row vba

Tags: vba

I need to create a sub to consolidate some data. I have several rows (anywhere from 4k to 20k) that I need to consolidate and sum the values from each column (from C to N).

The input data looks like this:

input
[image: input]

For the output, it should sum the columns for each SKU (Column A) and delete the rest.

Like this:

output
[image: output]

It should be simple enough, but I can’t seem to come up with an appropriate solution. I tried using an array with a scripting dictionary but I can’t figure out how to store more than a single value for each key. Sample (unfinished) code:

```
Dim sArray As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sArray = Range(currentRange).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(sArray, 1)
       For j = 3 To UBound(sArray, 2)
          If dict.exists(sArray(i, 1)) = False Then
             dict.Add sArray(i, 1), sArray(i, j)
      Else
     'this part is very wrong:
             dict(sArray(i, 1)) = dict(sArray(i, j)) + sArray(i, j)
          End If
       Next
Next
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution instead and it took 30 seconds to run it (not entirely my own idea, borrowed some code from someplace else):

```
    Sub dupes()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim RowNum As Long
    RowNum = 1

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set MyRange = Range("A2:N14200") 'for test only, on the real sub it's dynamic
    MyRange.Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending

    For Each Row In MyRange
        With Cells
            While Cells(RowNum, 1) = Cells(RowNum + 1, 1) And Cells(RowNum  + 1, 1) <> "" 'very important the second condition or it will continue to loop forever
                For i = 3 To 14
                    Cells(RowNum, i) = Cells(RowNum, i) + Cells(RowNum + 1, i)
                Next
                Rows(RowNum + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Wend
        End With
        RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Next
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    End Sub
```

It's kinda messy but it does the trick. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It sums the values in Column Q:AB then paste them back and removes the duplicates.

```
Sub dupremove()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet12") ' Change to your sheet

With ws
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("C2:N" & lastrow)
        .Offset(, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-14])"
        .Value = .Offset(, 14).Value
        .Offset(, 14).ClearContents
    End With
    With .Range("A1:N" & lastrow)
        .Value = .Value
        .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    End With


End With
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott! I tried this and it works fine but it took 15 minutes to sort 14k rows leaving 4.7k consolidated rows of data, that is turning off the ScreenUpdate and EnableEvents. Do you think there's a way to work on an array instead of directly on the cells? Thanks!

Comment: There is, you will need to store the input in one array and the output in another, then as you loop trough the input you will need to loop through the output to find matched then loop through the second dimension of that first to add the values.  so many many loops.  It will probably be quicker.

Comment: Out of curiosity @ScottCraner, why wouldn't you create a sheet and put the deduped Sku's and descs in there before doing your sumif to cut down on duplicate processing? If their data is dropping from 14K to 5K, thats going to triple the speed.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I tried looping trough the arrays and it ended up hanging pretty bad. Like you said, too many loops and I had to create a dictionary to dim the output  array first. Finally I tried working directly on the sheet instead of using arrays; sorting the data first and then deleting the row below. It took 30s, I'll post the code as a new answer. Thank you very much for your help man!

Comment: I would use a formula in evaluate to find the number of unique records instead of a dictionary, but you are correct there would be three loops going.  It does get messy and sometimes hard to follow. @Marcel